# Linux Command for Perl in Python

Tags: python, linux, perl

I am trying to this Linux command for Perl (v5.10.1) in Python (v2.6)

```
perl tilt.pl *.pdb > final.txt
```

What do I do so that I can apply the Perl script to every PDB file, examples would be best?

my current script is this:

```
import shlex, subprocess
arg_str = "perl tilt.pl frames > final.txt"
arg = shlex.split(arg_str)

print(arg)

import os
framespdb = os.listdir("prac_frames")

for frames in framespdb:
        subprocess.Popen(arg, stdout=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `shell=True`

BTW: I think you try to put variable `frames` in place of text `frames` in command so I use `%s` and `line % frames` to do this.

```
import os
import subprocess

line = "perl tilt.pl %s > final.txt"

framespdb = os.listdir("prac_frames")

for frames in framespdb:
    cmd = line % frames
    print(cmd)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

---

**EDIT:** if you need results in different files you can use again `%s` to add unique filename to command - for example:

```
import os
import subprocess

line = "perl tilt.pl %s > final-%s.txt" # second `%s`

framespdb = os.listdir("prac_frames")

for frames in framespdb:
    cmd = line % (frames, frames) # second `frames`
    print(cmd)
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

---

**EDIT:** normally in shell you can send result on screen or redirect it to file `> file.txt`. To get text on screen and save it in file you need shell command `tee` and python command `subprocess.check_output()`:

```
import os
import subprocess

line = "perl tilt.pl %s | tee final-%s.txt"

framespdb = os.listdir("prac_frames")


for frames in framespdb:
    cmd = line % (frames, frames)
    print(cmd)
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)
    print 'output:', output
```

Comment: That worked very well. How would I get the out put in a text file from this? I keep getting "Stop! File 'content from prac_frames' not not found!"

Comment: output goes to `final.txt` and overwrite previous result - you can use `>>` to get all results in `final.txt`. Or you can use another `%s` in `line` to save to different files. See new example in answer.

Comment: if you need result from perl script in python script then perl script has to print it on screen (it's call `output` in doumentation) but normal redirection `>` send result to file - not on screen. You need shell command `tee` to send perl script result on screen and into file. See new example.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a subprocess like from the shell if you override the shell parameter:

```
subprocess.call(arg_str, shell=True)
```